# @SequenceGenerator throws After saving the identifier must not be null! when value of id not passed in h2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am using spring boot with h2 database when using a sequence and using @SequenceGenerator doesn't seem to be generating the value for the primary key. I want to generate the value of Id by default and then update the values into the database.
Here are the details of my class.

CardHolder.java

```
package com.spring.book.rental.dao.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "card_holder")
public class CardHolder {

    @Id
    @Column
      @GeneratedValue(generator="SEQ_CARD_HOLDER_ID",strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_CARD_HOLDER_ID",
      sequenceName="SEQ_PG_CARD_HOLDER_ID",initialValue = 1)
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @Column(name = "card_number")
    public String cardNumber;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getCardNumber() {
        return cardNumber;
    }

    public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }
}
```

BookController.java

```
package com.spring.book.rental.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.spring.book.rental.DTO.BookDTO;
import com.spring.book.rental.DTO.RentBookRequest;
import com.spring.book.rental.service.BookService;

@RestController
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;
    
    @PostMapping(path="book-rental/rentABook", consumes = "application/json")
    public String rentABook(@RequestBody RentBookRequest bookRequest) {
        try {
            bookService.rentBook(bookRequest);
            return "You rented a Book Id : "+bookRequest.getBookId();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    
}
```

BookServiceImpl.java

```
package com.spring.book.rental.service.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.spring.book.rental.DTO.BookDTO;
import com.spring.book.rental.DTO.RentBookRequest;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.BookDAO;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.CardHolderDAO;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.RentalDAO;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.model.Book;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.model.CardHolder;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.model.Rental;
import com.spring.book.rental.service.BookService;

@Service("bookService")
@Component
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Autowired
    BookDAO bookDao;
    
    @Autowired
    CardHolderDAO cardHolderDAO;
    
    @Autowired
    RentalDAO rentalDAO;

    @Override
    public void rentBook(RentBookRequest bookRequest) throws Exception {
                    
        CardHolder cardHolder = new CardHolder();
        cardHolder.setFirstName(bookRequest.getFirstName());
        cardHolder.setLastName(bookRequest.getLastName());
        cardHolder.setCardNumber(bookRequest.getCardNumber());
        cardHolderDAO.addCardHolder(cardHolder);
        
        /* Rental rental = new Rental();
        rental.setBook_id(bookRequest.getBookId());
        rental.setCardHolder_id(cardHolder.getId());
        rentalDAO.addRental(rental); */
        
    }

}
```

CardHolderDAOImpl.java

```
package com.spring.book.rental.dao.impl;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.spring.book.rental.dao.CardHolderDAO;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.model.CardHolder;
import com.spring.book.rental.dao.repository.CardHolderRepository;

@Repository
public class CardHolderDAOImpl implements CardHolderDAO {

    @Autowired
    CardHolderRepository cardHolderRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void addCardHolder(CardHolder cardHolder) {
        cardHolderRepository.save(cardHolder);
    }
    
}
```

CardHolderRepository.java

```
package com.spring.book.rental.dao.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.spring.book.rental.dao.model.CardHolder;

public interface CardHolderRepository extends CrudRepository<CardHolder, Integer> {

    public Optional<CardHolder> findById(Integer id);
}
```

RentBookRequest.java

```
package com.spring.book.rental.DTO;

public class RentBookRequest {

    private int bookId;
    
    private int cardHolderId;
    
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName;
    
    private String cardNumber;

    public int getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(int bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

    public int getCardHolderId() {
        return cardHolderId;
    }

    public void setCardHolderId(int cardHolderId) {
        this.cardHolderId = cardHolderId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCardNumber() {
        return cardNumber;
    }

    public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }
    
}
```

Here is the main class

SpringTaskBookRentalApplication.java

```
package com.spring.book.rental;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import sun.misc.Contended;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTaskBookRentalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTaskBookRentalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have added this in the application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bookrentaldb
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.separator=;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

Here is the schema.sql file

```
create table BOOK(
    id int not null primary key,
    title varchar(50) not null,
    IS_BOOK_AVAILABLE boolean not null,
    author varchar(50) not null,
    primary key(id)
);

create table card_holder (
    id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    card_number varchar(20),
    primary key(id)
);

create table Rental(
    rental_id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cardHolder_id int not null,
    book_id int not null
);

 CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_PG_CARD_HOLDER_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1  NOCYCLE ;
 
 CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_PG_Rental_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 100   NOCYCLE ;
```

Here is the data.sql

```
insert into BOOK (id,title,IS_BOOK_AVAILABLE,author) values (101,'A Thousand Splendid Suns','true','Khalid Hosseini');

insert into BOOK (id,title,IS_BOOK_AVAILABLE,author) values (102,'Head First Design Patterns','true','Elisabeth Freeman and Kathy Sierra');

insert into BOOK (id,title,IS_BOOK_AVAILABLE,author) values (103,'Head First Java','true','Book by Bert Bates and Kathy Sierra');

commit;
```

I have tried several other things with @GeneratedValue

```
@Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
```

This is the stackTrace of error I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: After saving the identifier must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.spring.book.rental.dao.impl.CardHolderDAOImpl.addCardHolder(CardHolderDAOImpl.java:38)
    at com.spring.book.rental.dao.impl.CardHolderDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8e01a85d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.spring.book.rental.dao.impl.CardHolderDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6f1054.addCardHolder(<generated>)
    at com.spring.book.rental.service.impl.BookServiceImpl.rentBook(BookServiceImpl.java:68)
    at com.spring.book.rental.controller.BookController.rentABook(BookController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding lot of dependencies which you don't need. And when you add a dependency that you don't need, spring boot tries to guess the type of your application and configures accordingly.

I also recommend reading Spring data JPA vs Spring Data JDBC as both are mixed.

1.

```
    public CardHolder addCardHolder(CardHolder cardHolder) {
        return cardHolderRepository.save(cardHolder);
    }
```

2. 

```
    @Override
    public void rentBook(RentBookRequest bookRequest) throws Exception {
                    
        CardHolder cardHolder = new CardHolder();
        cardHolder.setFirstName(bookRequest.getFirstName());
        cardHolder.setLastName(bookRequest.getLastName());
        cardHolder.setCardNumber(bookRequest.getCardNumber());
        CardHolder saved = cardHolderDAO.addCardHolder(cardHolder);
        
        Rental rental = new Rental();
        rental.setBook_id(bookRequest.getBookId());
        rental.setCardHolder_id(saved.getId());
        rentalDAO.addRental(rental); 
        
    }
```

3. Your pom should contain only the following. You are currently adding many different dependencies

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

4. 

```
package com.spring.book.rental.dao.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    
    @Column
    public String title;

    @Column(name = "IS_BOOK_AVAILABLE")
    public boolean isBookAvailable;
    
    @Column
    public String author;
...
```

5. 

```
package com.spring.book.rental.dao.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "card_holder")
public class CardHolder {

    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(generator="SEQ_CARD_HOLDER_ID",strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_CARD_HOLDER_ID", sequenceName="SEQ_PG_CARD_HOLDER_ID",initialValue = 1)
    @Column
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @Column(name = "card_number")
    public String cardNumber;
....
```

6. 

```
package com.spring.book.rental.dao.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Rental")
public class Rental {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "rental_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int rentalId;

    @Column(name = "cardHolder_id")
    public int cardHolder_id;

    @Column(name = "book_id")
    public int book_id;
....
```

7. 

```
package com.spring.book.rental.dao.repository;

import com.spring.book.rental.dao.model.Book;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book,Integer>{

    public List<Book> findAllByIsBookAvailableTrue();
    
    public List<Book> findAll();
    
    public Optional<Book> findById(Integer id);
}
...
```

8. Delete `schema.sql` as it has mistakes and JPA can auto create it.
9. application properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true 
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Comment: Have tried with this also, still it is throwing the same error, by referring the given link it throws IllegalArgumentException when the entity is null, that means it is not generating the Id from the sequence.

Comment: I have updated the question with the stack trace, pls check

Comment: As both the files are not there how will it create tables and insert the records,I m getting errors on the other function regarding the same as table does not exists.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I can't delete data.sql as I ll be needing book table records to be added at the time of running.

Comment: I have just changed some of the annotations and removed all things from application.properties just added what u have mentioned. And one more thing for CardHolder.java I only added  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) for generation and it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add @Repository annotation to the repository interface.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).